# Как интегрировать framework в тему wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, framework, wordpress-плагины

Кто ниб-нибудь подскажите , как интегрировать фреймворк в тему? 
Чтобы использовать его не с плагинов, а только в моей теме, и при переключении на другую тему его работа была невозможна?

Фреймворк Unyson (ThemeFuse) , сетка bootstrap.

Comment: В мануале пишется что необходимо включить bootstrap.php файл.

Answer (score 0):

всем спасибо, решил вопрос, у каждого фреймворка по разному, нужно просто подключить файл сетки в тему командой include.